# Sending Image From Python to Android Phone

Tags: android, python-3.x, bluetooth

I have a problem about bluetooth communication between android phone and pc. Firstly, I want to send an image from a PC to Android phone.

Let me show my codes Android side

Handler:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch(msg.what){
                case STATE_LISTENING:
                    status.setText("LISTENING");
                    break;
                case STATE_CONNECTING:
                    status.setText("Connecting");
                    break;
                case STATE_CONNECTED:
                    status.setText("Connected");
                    break;
                case STATE_CONNECTION_FAILED:
                    status.setText("Connection Failed");
                    break;
                case STATE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED:
                   byte[] readBuff = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                   Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(readBuff,0,msg.arg1);
                   imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

SendRecieve class:

```
    public class SendReceive extends Thread{
    private final BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket;
    private final Handler _handler;
    private final InputStream inputStream;
    private final OutputStream outputStream;
    public  SendReceive(BluetoothSocket socket, Handler handler){
        bluetoothSocket = socket;
        InputStream tempIn = null;
        OutputStream tempOut = null;
        _handler = handler;
        try {
            tempIn = bluetoothSocket.getInputStream();
            tempOut = bluetoothSocket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        inputStream = tempIn;
        outputStream = tempOut;

    }
    public void run(){
        byte[] buffer = null;
        int numberOfBytes = 0;
        int index =  0;
        boolean flag = true;

        while(true){
            if(flag){
                try {
                    byte[] temp = new byte[inputStream.available()];
                    if(inputStream.read(temp)>0){
                      numberOfBytes = Integer.parseInt(new String(temp,"UTF-8"));
                        buffer = new byte[numberOfBytes];
                        flag = false;

                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }else{
                try {
                    byte[] data = new byte[inputStream.available()];
                    int numbers = inputStream.read(data);

                    System.arraycopy(data,0,buffer,index,numbers);
                    index = index+numbers;
                    if(index == numberOfBytes){
                        _handler.obtainMessage(MainActivity.STATE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED, numberOfBytes,-1,buffer).sendToTarget();
                         flag = true;
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }
    public void write(byte[] bytes){
        try {
            outputStream.write(bytes);
            outputStream.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Python codes:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import bluetooth
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('MyImage.png')
im_resize = im.resize((500, 500))
buf = io.BytesIO()
im_resize.save(buf, format='PNG')
byte_im = buf.getvalue()

def connect (bd_addr,port,message):
    sock=bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
    sock.connect((bd_addr, port))
    sock.send(message)
    sock.close() 

addr = "XX:XX:XX:XX"  
services = bluetooth.find_service(address=addr)
for svc in services:
    if svc["name"] == b'BluetoothProject\x00': #Name of Android Project
           connect(addr,svc["port"], byte_im)
    else:
        print("Bluetooth is offline or smth else")
```

I can send text messages without any problem but could not send an image. 
Error is in Android side : java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string. It can not convert string to int(SendRecieve class,  numberOfBytes = Integer.parseInt(new String(temp,"UTF-8")).

How should I send image and which format from python side? What is the correct way?.

And I also tried send as base64 format. Then, the error was "bad-base 64" and numberofbytes line again.
Can you help me for my problem? Thanks.!!

Comment: python will first send an integer indicating the size of the image that follows. So the amount of bytes of the image. After sending that integer (four bytes) it sends all the image bytes.

Comment: On the receiving side first that integer will be read. So read four bytes. Then you will know the amount of bytes that are gonna come and you can declare for instance already a buffer big enough to hold the image. If you just want to write the image to file then you do not need a buffer but can write the received bytes to an outputstream.

Comment: You can also send an image in base64 format. If it did not work then you did something wrong or sent an image not recognised by Android.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your answer. In debugging mode I can see bytes in this code:
 `byte[] temp = new byte[inputStream.available()]; `
like temp: {-119,80,78...}  how can i get the size of the image can you explain a bit detailed.

Comment: How to handle the size of the image both on sending and receiving side i already told you.